# Apache Beam with Dataflow - Writing to BigQuery with java.time.Instant type fields fails with @DefaultSchema(JavaFieldSchema.class)

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow, apache-beam-io

I'm trying to run the below pipeline on dataflow with **DataflowRunner**  using **@DefaultSchema(JavaFieldSchema.class)** with Beam to auto create schema but it fails with error below

```
Unable to generate a creator for POJO 'class java.time.Instant' with inferred schema: Fields: Options:{{}} Note POJOs must have a zero-argument constructor, or a constructor annotated with @SchemaCreate
```

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var options =
                PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().as(BigqueryPipelineOptions.class);
        var pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);
        var tableName = new TableName(options.getInputTable().get());
        Create.Values<SchemaPojo> dataset = Create.of(
                new SchemaPojo("a", Instant.EPOCH, new Child("1")),
                new SchemaPojo(null, Instant.EPOCH, new Child("111")),
                new SchemaPojo("c", Instant.EPOCH, new Child("111111")),
                new SchemaPojo("d", null, null));
        pipeline.getSchemaRegistry().registerPOJO(Instant.class);
        pipeline.apply(dataset)
                .apply("Print", ParDo.of(new PrintLog<>()));
        pipeline.run();
    }


    @Data
    @Builder
    @DefaultSchema(JavaFieldSchema.class)
    @NoArgsConstructor
    static class SchemaPojo {
        @Nullable String poNum;
        @Nullable Instant timestamp;
        @Nullable Child child;

        @SchemaCreate
        public SchemaPojo(String poNum, Instant timestamp, Child child) {
            this.poNum = poNum;
            this.timestamp = timestamp;
            this.child = child;
        }

    }

    @Data
    @Builder
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @DefaultSchema(JavaFieldSchema.class)
    static class Child {
        @Nullable String type;

        @SchemaCreate
        public Child(String type) {
            this.type = type;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated on how to write Instant types using beam schema auto-create, Thanks!

Comment: this looks like a bug form lack of suport of the `java.utils.Instant` type - cna you try with an `org.joda.time.Instant` class property instead?